# How to scan an image and automatically crop it to the scanned content with a linux command line tool?

Tags: linux, command-line, scanner, crop

I need to scan lots of small items with quite similar, but not the exact same, size.

What I thought I'd like to do is:

Run a Linux command line tool with the file name as a parameter which runs the scanner until about 10% of the whole scanner size and crops the image to the content that is not white (a square would be fine).

Does anybody know if this is possible and when how?

Answer (score 3):

What you need is `convert` from [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). First install `imagemagick` for your distribution. On debian derived systems run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Now, if you just want to remove whitespace do this:

```
for image in $(find . -name "*png" | sed 's/.png//'); do convert -trim $image.png $image_trimmed.png; done
```

This assumes your images are PNGs, if not change the above line accordingly.

If you need fancier resizing, have a look at the [imagemagick documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#resize), you can do just about anything you can imagine with it.

So, your actual workflow would be:

1. Scan your images and save them in the same folder.
2. Run the command I gave above in that folder.

Comment: This doesn't work for my test image. No white pixel gets removed.

Comment: @hennr, try my updated suggestion. There should now be a file called test_trimmed.png.

Comment: @terdon I already ran the correct command whith the output file, but trim doesn't work with my scanned image. Note that a color scan doesn't provide perfectly clean white pixels.

Comment: Well, you can play around with the -white-threshold parameter to convert almost white pixels to completely white pixels. This just works for dark scanned content though.

Comment: Ah, i see what you mean @hennr. Sorry, i did not take the scan into account, I have used this command succesfully but on perfectly white images. I don't have time to write an answer now, but try gimp scripting, it might work for you.

Comment: @hennr, You _did_ say "white" in your question mind you :)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `-fuzz`:

```
-fuzz *distance*
```

Colors within that distance are considered equal.

```
for image in $(find . -name "*png" | sed 's/.png//');
do convert -fuzz 255 -trim $image.png $image_trimmed.png; done
```

Answer (score 2):

As [said here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/689445/29674), by reading [this blog post](https://www.opensourceforu.com/2015/03/automate-the-cropping-of-photos-from-scanned-album-pages/), I found [this bash script](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/multicrop/index.php) which uses [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/) : download it, `chmod +x` it and then I managed to rotate & crop my scanned photos with the following command:

```
multicrop -c 50,50 -f 40 -d 50 scanned_photo_in.jpg extracted_photo_out.jpg
```

- `-c 50,50` is to detect the background color from pixel at 50,50 (default is 0,0)
- `-f 40` is the "fuzz value for separating background color expressed as percent" (default is 10)
- `-d 50` will discard any region that has a width or height smaller than this size (default is to not discard anything)

Here is a bash script to run this command for any jpg files in the current folder and put the extracted photos in `extracted` sub folder:

```bsh
mkdir extracted; for PHOTO in *.jpg; do multicrop -c 50,50 -f 40 -d 50 $PHOTO extracted/$PHOTO; done
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue: I had tons of scanned pictures and was looking for a method to crop the rectangular photo and discard the white areas.

None of the methods listed here or in other forums worked for me.

Closest to work was [@anthony-o answer](https://superuser.com/a/1703389/167207) by using the [`multicrop`](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/multicrop/) script.

But for my particular case, I had to reduce fuzzy; otherwise, it was cropping parts of the image from the picture. Also, I had to add pruning to avoid noisy areas. (dirty from the scanners, borders, etc). This is the command I used:

```
./multicrop.sh -c 1600,2200 -p 20 Imagen.jpg  extracted/out.jpg
```